# How can I disable/remove upper right corner "x" from a Foundation Joyride?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

**Edit 7/16/15**: I ended up using this between the `<li>` tags of the joyride I needed the "x" disabled on.
`<script>$('.joyride-close-tip').remove();</script>`
Not the most clean solution but does what i need.

**Original Post**
Documentation is [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html)

If you open up the documentation page where they have a joyride example, all the joyrides will have a "x" in the upper right corner, but I don't want to have that show on **most** of the joyrides.

As far as I know, it's not good practice to remove the $joyride-tip-close elements from the .scss files. I also wanted to know how to do this without having to basically copy and paste all the joyride scss without the joyride-close-tip portion (which seems to be what styles the "x").

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

find that class `class="joyride-close-tip"`

override it with `display:none;`

Comment: I should clarify that even if I did along the lines of:

`<ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
  <li data-id="firstStop" data-text="Next" data-options="tip_location: top; prev_button: false">
    <p>Hello and welcome to the Joyride <br>documentation page.</p>
  </li>
  <li data-id="numero1" data-class="custom so-awesome" data-text="Next" data-prev-text="Prev">
    <h4>Stop #1</h4>
    <p>You can control all the details for you tour stop. Any valid HTML will work inside of Joyride.</p>
  </li>
</ol> `

With no mention of the joyride-close-tip class, then the x still shows up regardless.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this by specifying a blank template for `link` in the options. But to do this you need to redefine the HTML templates, like this…

```
$(document).foundation({
  joyride: {
    template: {
      link        : '',
      tip         : '<div class="joyride-tip-guide"><span class="joyride-nub"></span></div>',
      wrapper     : '<div class="joyride-content-wrapper"></div>',
      button      : '<a href="#" class="small button joyride-next-tip"></a>',
      prev_button : '<a href="#" class="small button joyride-prev-tip"></a>'
    }
  }
}).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

See http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html

Comment: Instead of redefine you can do:
`template: $.extend(true, {}, Foundation.libs.joyride.defaults.template, {link: ''})`